# When do a UIViews bounds get updated?

Tags: iphone, uiview, bounds

In the [Apple documentation on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6), they indicate that UIView bounds are automatically set when you initialize with a frame.

Are bounds automatically set at any other time?  Specifically I've run into some weirdness with rotating back and forth from portrait mode and landscape.  Do bounds get recalculated then?  Any other times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `autoresizeMask` set on your view, then its bounds may change when its superview's bounds change. Other than that, I cannot think of any "automatic" bounds changes - only things like setting the frame or calling `-sizeToFit` should change the bounds.

Comment: I think the weirdness I encountered was probably due to UIScrollViews setting their bounds orgins to non zero values.  So when the parent rotates, the scroll view's bounds don't necessarily adjust as expected.